# General Update Pattern with d3 for Histograms with rectangles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-science, histogram, data-analysis

I am facing this issue where I am trying to achieve histogram with elements separated and visible for the particular bin. But when the data changes, everything goes in the enter() and nothing goes in the update it seems. So all the existing elements also transition and come from the top rather than just displacing their values. Please have a look at the code I have attached below which produces the output as image attached. Not able to figure out why update is not working an only enter there. I cannot share the entire code but this is the main problem here.[image]

HTML structure - [image]

```js
let initialRender = true;
let selectedData1 = true;
const margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

function printChart(asd, data, dataGradients) {
  const svg = d3.select('#data-viz')
  // const isZoomed = map.getZoom() > zoomThreshold;

  // if (isZoomed !== changedZoom) {
  //   initialRender = true;
  //   changedZoom = isZoomed;
  // }

  // X axis and scale ------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => d.value)))
    .range([0, width])

  const xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"))
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSizeOuter(0);

  let xAxis = null
  if (initialRender) {
    d3.select(".axis-x").remove()
    xAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis-x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 115 + ")")
    initialRender = false
  } else {
    xAxis = d3.select(".axis-x")
  }

  xAxis.transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease(d3.easeSinInOut)
    .call(xAxisCall)
  // X axis and scale <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------------------------
  const binMin = 5;
  const binMax = 150;
  const tDuration = 3000;

  // Just to calculate max elements in each bin ---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  let histogram = d3.histogram()
    .value(d => d.value)
    .domain(xScale.domain())
    .thresholds(xScale.ticks(10));

  let bins = histogram(data).filter(d => d.length > 0);
  console.log(bins);
  const max = d3.max(bins.map(bin => bin.length))
  const maxBinSize = max <= 10 ? 10 : max
  // Just to calculate max elements in each bin <<<<<<<<<<<<----------------

  // Decide parameters for histogram ------------>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  const dotSizeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([binMin, binMax])
    .range([10, 4])
  const dotSize = dotSizeScale(maxBinSize);

  const dotSpacingScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([binMin, binMax])
    .range([12, 6])
  const dotSpacing = dotSpacingScale(maxBinSize);

  const thresholdScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([binMin, binMax])
    .range([10, 100])
  const threshold = thresholdScale(maxBinSize);

  const yTransformMarginScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([binMin, binMax])
    .range([100, 100])
  const yTransformMargin = yTransformMarginScale(maxBinSize);

  if (dotSize !== 10) {
    d3.selectAll('.gBin').remove()
    d3.selectAll('rect').remove()
  }

  histogram = d3.histogram()
    .value(d => d.value)
    .domain(xScale.domain())
    .thresholds(xScale.ticks(threshold));

  bins = histogram(data).filter(d => d.length > 0);
  // Decide parameters for histogram <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------------------

  // Y axis scale -------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(bins, (d) => d.length)]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis-y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
  d3.select(".axis-y")
    .remove()
  // Y axis scale <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------------

  const binGroup = svg.selectAll(".gBin")
    .data(bins,
      (d) => {
        console.log('id 1', d.x0)
        return d.x0
      }
    )

  binGroup
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove()

  const binGroupEnter = binGroup
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .merge(binGroup)
    .attr("class", "gBin")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + xScale(d.x0) + "," + yTransformMargin + ")";
    })
    .attr("width", 10)

  const elements = binGroupEnter.selectAll("rect")
    .data(d => d.map((p, i) => ({
        id: p.id,
        idx: i,
        value: p.value,
      })),
      function(d) {
        console.log('id 2', d)
        return d.id
      }
    )

  elements.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(tDuration)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove()

  elements
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(elements)
    .attr("y", -(height + margin.top))
    // .on("mouseover", tooltipOn)
    // .on("mouseout", tooltipOff)
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return 50 * i;
    })
    .duration(tDuration)
    .attr("id", d => d.value)
    .attr("y", (d, i) => -(i * dotSpacing))
    .attr("width", dotSize)
    .attr("height", dotSize)
    // .style("fill", (d) => getBinColor(d.value, dataGradients))
    .style("fill", 'red')
}

const data1 = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 14
}, {
  id: 13,
  value: 12
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 50
}, {
  id: 32,
  value: 142
}]
const data2 = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 135
}, {
  id: 7,
  value: 2
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 50
}, {
  id: 32,
  value: 50
}]
printChart(null, data1, null)

function changeData() {
  selectedData1 ?
    printChart(null, data2, null) :
    printChart(null, data1, null)
  selectedData1 = !selectedData1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="550" height="250" id="data-viz">
      <g transform="translate(30, 100)">
      </g>
    </svg>
<button onclick="changeData()"> Update data </button>
```

Comment: Do you call this entire block of code again when updating your histogram?  It would certainly help if you added a fully reproducible example instead of just cute and paste from your code.

Comment: @Mark I would like to share but the private keys for map etc so I am not sharing code. I can give you the details though. I am trying to achieve something like - https://www.opportunityatlas.org/.  Here if you proceed and look at top right corner and change the map the elements have smooth transition. Trying to replicate the same. You can select one of the elements and see it also.

The structure I am making is something like this from the above code

Comment: @Mark  There are g element bins with class .gBin and in those bins are rectangles for each element. I have also provided unique key with second callback method of data binding. x0 for each bin and the actual id from data for each rect in bin. Please help me out for the same. Everytime the graph goes into enter and never into update. I have attached snapshot of HTML structure in the question for reference.

Comment: In this example https://www.opportunityatlas.org/. Top right corner click on show distribution and select on screen then change the on screen map this will change the plotting but the already present elements change position and other elements come from top as part of enter transition but in my case everything is enter and nothing is update. I do not know if I have implemented the right way.

Comment: @Mark I have changed the code snippet also. Please have a look. The id's of the data are same but still they all come in enter() phase.

Comment: Updated question with proper code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393713/d3js-updating-histogram-elements-not-working-general-update-pattern