# D3js Updating Histogram elements not working (General Update Pattern)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-science, data-visualization, data-analysis

I am trying to accomplish something similar to what is here : https://www.opportunityatlas.org/. If you proceed further to this link and click on **'Show Distribution'** to see the graph and select **'On Screen'** and then move the cursor around the map you will see the size of the rectangles changes and also the update patterns works i.e. if a rectangle was already there it moves horizontally to the new value.

I have tried doing the same but **could not achieve the update part**. Could you please point me out where I missed out. I have attached a part of my code where there are two data sets ***data1*** and ***data2*** with some id's common but as you can see when you click on update to change the data set all rectangles are in the enter phase and none of them change position for existing ones (none in update phase). It will be helpful if someone can guide me through this one. If there is some other way to implement the same graph that I provided in the link, that would also be helpful if there is some other approach. ***Thanks in advance !***

```js
let initialRender = true;
let selectedData1 = true;
const margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

function printChart(asd, data, dataGradients) {
  const svg = d3.select('#data-viz')
  // const isZoomed = map.getZoom() > zoomThreshold;

  // if (isZoomed !== changedZoom) {
  //   initialRender = true;
  //   changedZoom = isZoomed;
  // }

  // X axis and scale ------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => d.value)))
    .range([0, width])

  const xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"))
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSizeOuter(0);

  let xAxis = null
  if (initialRender) {
    d3.select(".axis-x").remove()
    xAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis-x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 115 + ")")
    initialRender = false
  } else {
    xAxis = d3.select(".axis-x")
  }

  xAxis.transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease(d3.easeSinInOut)
    .call(xAxisCall)
  // X axis and scale <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------------------------
  const binMin = 5;
  const binMax = 150;
  const tDuration = 3000;

  // Just to calculate max elements in each bin ---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  let histogram = d3.histogram()
    .value(d => d.value)
    .domain(xScale.domain())
    .thresholds(xScale.ticks(10));

  let bins = histogram(data).filter(d => d.length > 0);
  console.log(bins);
  const max = d3.max(bins.map(bin => bin.length))
  const maxBinSize = max <= 10 ? 10 : max
  // Just to calculate max elements in each bin <<<<<<<<<<<<----------------

  // Decide parameters for histogram ------------>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  const dotSizeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([binMin, binMax])
    .range([10, 4])
  const dotSize = dotSizeScale(maxBinSize);

  const dotSpacingScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([binMin, binMax])
    .range([12, 6])
  const dotSpacing = dotSpacingScale(maxBinSize);

  const thresholdScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([binMin, binMax])
    .range([10, 100])
  const threshold = thresholdScale(maxBinSize);

  const yTransformMarginScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([binMin, binMax])
    .range([100, 100])
  const yTransformMargin = yTransformMarginScale(maxBinSize);

  if (dotSize !== 10) {
    d3.selectAll('.gBin').remove()
    d3.selectAll('rect').remove()
  }

  histogram = d3.histogram()
    .value(d => d.value)
    .domain(xScale.domain())
    .thresholds(xScale.ticks(threshold));

  bins = histogram(data).filter(d => d.length > 0);
  // Decide parameters for histogram <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------------------

  // Y axis scale -------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(bins, (d) => d.length)]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis-y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
  d3.select(".axis-y")
    .remove()
  // Y axis scale <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------------

  const binGroup = svg.selectAll(".gBin")
    .data(bins,
      (d) => {
        console.log('id 1', d.x0)
        return d.x0
      }
    )

  binGroup
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove()

  const binGroupEnter = binGroup
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .merge(binGroup)
    .attr("class", "gBin")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + xScale(d.x0) + "," + yTransformMargin + ")";
    })
    .attr("width", 10)

  const elements = binGroupEnter.selectAll("rect")
    .data(d => d.map((p, i) => ({
        id: p.id,
        idx: i,
        value: p.value,
      })),
      function(d) {
        console.log('id 2', d)
        return d.id
      }
    )

  elements.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(tDuration)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove()

  elements
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(elements)
    .attr("y", -(height + margin.top))
    // .on("mouseover", tooltipOn)
    // .on("mouseout", tooltipOff)
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return 50 * i;
    })
    .duration(tDuration)
    .attr("id", d => d.value)
    .attr("y", (d, i) => -(i * dotSpacing))
    .attr("width", dotSize)
    .attr("height", dotSize)
    // .style("fill", (d) => getBinColor(d.value, dataGradients))
    .style("fill", 'red')
}

const data1 = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 14
}, {
  id: 13,
  value: 12
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 50
}, {
  id: 32,
  value: 142
}]
const data2 = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 135
}, {
  id: 7,
  value: 2
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 50
}, {
  id: 32,
  value: 50
}]
printChart(null, data1, null)

function changeData() {
  selectedData1 ?
    printChart(null, data2, null) :
    printChart(null, data1, null)
  selectedData1 = !selectedData1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeData()"> Update data </button>
<svg width="550" height="250" id="data-viz">
      <g transform="translate(30, 100)">
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be these lines:

```
if (dotSize !== 10) {
  d3.selectAll('.gBin').remove();
  d3.selectAll('rect').remove();
}
```

All your elements are removed before any selections are calculated so everything (both your bin `g` and element `rect`) become `enter`.

Another interesting thing is your data key for your bins.  Since you are using the `x0` your `g` will also enter/exit depending on how the histogram function calculates the bins.

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <button onclick="changeData()">Update data</button>
  <svg width="550" height="250" id="data-viz">
    <g transform="translate(30, 100)"></g>
  </svg>
  <script>
    let initialRender = true;
    let selectedData1 = true;
    const margin = {
        top: 10,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 30,
      },
      width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    function printChart(asd, data, dataGradients) {
    
      console.clear();
    
      const svg = d3.select('#data-viz');
      // const isZoomed = map.getZoom() > zoomThreshold;

      // if (isZoomed !== changedZoom) {
      //   initialRender = true;
      //   changedZoom = isZoomed;
      // }

      // X axis and scale ------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      const xScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data.map((d) => d.value)))
        .range([0, width]);

      const xAxisCall = d3
        .axisBottom(xScale)
        .tickFormat(d3.format('.2s'))
        .ticks(5)
        .tickSizeOuter(0);

      let xAxis = null;
      if (initialRender) {
        d3.select('.axis-x').remove();
        xAxis = svg
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'axis-x')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + 115 + ')');
        initialRender = false;
      } else {
        xAxis = d3.select('.axis-x');
      }

      xAxis.transition().duration(2000).ease(d3.easeSinInOut).call(xAxisCall);
      // X axis and scale <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------------------------
      const binMin = 5;
      const binMax = 150;
      const tDuration = 3000;

      // Just to calculate max elements in each bin ---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      let histogram = d3
        .histogram()
        .value((d) => d.value)
        .domain(xScale.domain())
        .thresholds(xScale.ticks(10));

      let bins = histogram(data).filter((d) => d.length > 0);
      //console.log(bins);
      const max = d3.max(bins.map((bin) => bin.length));
      const maxBinSize = max <= 10 ? 10 : max;
      // Just to calculate max elements in each bin <<<<<<<<<<<<----------------

      // Decide parameters for histogram ------------>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      const dotSizeScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([binMin, binMax])
        .range([10, 4]);
      const dotSize = dotSizeScale(maxBinSize);

      const dotSpacingScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([binMin, binMax])
        .range([12, 6]);
      const dotSpacing = dotSpacingScale(maxBinSize);

      const thresholdScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([binMin, binMax])
        .range([10, 100]);
      const threshold = thresholdScale(maxBinSize);

      const yTransformMarginScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([binMin, binMax])
        .range([100, 100]);
      const yTransformMargin = yTransformMarginScale(maxBinSize);

      /*
      if (dotSize !== 10) {
        d3.selectAll('.gBin').remove()
        d3.selectAll('rect').remove()
      }
      */

      histogram = d3
        .histogram()
        .value((d) => d.value)
        .domain(xScale.domain())
        .thresholds(xScale.ticks(threshold));

      bins = histogram(data).filter((d) => d.length > 0);
      // Decide parameters for histogram <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------------------

      // Y axis scale -------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

      yScale.domain([0, d3.max(bins, (d) => d.length)]);
      svg.append('g').attr('class', 'axis-y').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
      d3.select('.axis-y').remove();
      // Y axis scale <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------------

      const binGroup = svg.selectAll('.gBin').data(bins, (d) => {
        //console.log('id 1', d.x0)
        return d.x0;
      });

      binGroup.exit().transition().duration(2000).style('opacity', 0).remove();

      const binGroupEnter = binGroup
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .merge(binGroup)
        .attr('class', 'gBin')
        .attr('x', 1)
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
          return 'translate(' + xScale(d.x0) + ',' + yTransformMargin + ')';
        })
        .attr('width', 10);

      const elements = binGroupEnter.selectAll('rect').data(
        (d) =>
          d.map((p, i) => ({
            id: p.id,
            idx: i,
            value: p.value,
          })),
        function (d) {
          //console.log('id 2', d)
          return d.id;
        }
      );

      let eex = elements
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(tDuration)
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .remove();

      console.log("rects exiting", eex.nodes().map(e => "rect" + e.getAttribute('id')))

      let een = elements
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('id', (d) => d.value);

      console.log("rects entering", een.nodes().map(e => "rect" + e.getAttribute('id')))

      let eem = een
        .merge(elements);

      console.log("rects merge", eem.nodes().map(e => "rect" + e.getAttribute('id')))

      eem
        .attr('y', -(height + margin.top))
        // .on("mouseover", tooltipOn)
        // .on("mouseout", tooltipOff)
        .transition()
        .delay(function (d, i) {
          return 50 * i;
        })
        .duration(tDuration)
        .attr('y', (d, i) => -(i * dotSpacing))
        .attr('width', dotSize)
        .attr('height', dotSize)
        // .style("fill", (d) => getBinColor(d.value, dataGradients))
        .style('fill', 'red');
    }

    const data1 = [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: 14,
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        value: 12,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: 50,
      },
      {
        id: 32,
        value: 142,
      },
    ];
    const data2 = [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: 135,
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        value: 2,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: 50,
      },
      {
        id: 32,
        value: 50,
      },
    ];
    printChart(null, data1, null);

    function changeData() {
      selectedData1
        ? printChart(null, data2, null)
        : printChart(null, data1, null);
      selectedData1 = !selectedData1;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried removing the two lines but still no effect. The elements still don't update. Could you help me replicate what I showed in the link above ? It would be really helpful if you can do the same and help me. I would be greatful.

Comment: @KishanVikani, I guess I'm failing to understand **what data you think** should be computed as a update.  Right now, any `rect` has to meet multiple criteria to be an update:  1.) in the same bin as last time 2.) that bin has to be calculated to have the same `.x0` as the previous data.  Oh, and in the link you sent, I must be missing something, I just see an interesting map.  I can't find any histograms.

Comment: If you see the top right, there is a section. Where you can click on Show Distribution. Then you'll be able to see the graph. Select on screen tab and then move the map the histogram will change. And yes we need to keep track of two things. 1) the rect changing bins and 2) changing position in the same bin.

Comment: Yess but you see my code is not doing what the link is doing. That transitions you see when you move on the map or change any parameters. The axis transition is working but the bins are not moving smoothly to new position. They are coming as enter from top and not moving from old to new position in my code. The link above is soo appealing and done properly.

Comment: @KishanVikani, are you looking for it to behave [like this](https://plnkr.co/edit/U3LvnlQp57rqlMM7?preview); where the individual `rects` are tracked by **id only** regardless of bin?

Comment: Yes something like that actually. I'll check if that helps coz it looks like it does. Thanks for trying it out man.

Comment: I face one more issue here. When the values are like - 1,2,6,10,23. The plot works perfectly fine but when I have large sets of data with varying range like 1,2,5,12,1000,25000, The scale and bin size is an issue coz there might but many values from 1-100 and only one value >1000 which shows separately on the scale and the rectangles also reduce in size due to many values in the 1-100 bins. Can you help me out on how do I rescale my domain for x-axis and bins also ?